# Blackberry AppWorld webframe

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to build a webframe application in Java for Blackberry AppWorld. I need an app page that will show a website without leaving the application. In iOS, this would be a UIWebView or in Android, this would be a webframe.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [BrowserField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html).